# arXiv preprint "on hold"

Tags: arxiv

I recently submitted a preprint to arXiv, and it has now been "on hold" for 3 weeks. There is nothing obvious wrong or questionable with the paper in my view, and I have around 20 of other arXiv preprints.

I have not experienced any delays like this before (once or twice there has been a delay of 1-2 days). After 10 days, I used the arXiv form to contact the moderators who told me that the moderators have been informed that my submission still needs a decision (and that they can't give me any exact reason for why the paper is on hold), but nothing has happened in the 10 days since.

Are these extreme delays common, and what should I do? Can I just delete the submission and submit it again (the rules on the "on hold" help page only state that one should not submit the same paper again while it is on hold, but don't mention the case of deleting the old submission).

Comment: I would guess that deleting the submission then resubmitting it would be the opposite of helpful: it would either look like trying to sneak around moderation, or else you'll get pushed to the back of the moderation queue.

Comment: I have the same issue now (exactly 3 weeks since submitting). Did you have it published finally? if yes then how much did it take until the moderators finally took a decision?

Comment: @KratosMath yes, it was published after something like 4-5 weeks in the end. The only visible effect was that the main and second category were switched by the admins.

Comment: https://ramblingacademic.com/2015/12/17/beware-delays-in-arxiv-posts/ suggests that categorization errors (in the view of the editors) trigger moderation and can trigger long delays.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Such delays are now common. The reasons were not explained publicly and we can only speculate. Maybe has something to do with people putting preprints on arXiv and then trying to use them to get credibility for their argument in a public debate (e.g. related to epidemics but not limited to this topic).

You should not delete the submission. Just wait patiently and it will eventually be checked by a moderator and then announced and appear online.

Comment: Thanks, I was just shocked by the 3 weeks which never happened to me before.